# Post increments

Tags: arrays, increment

I have been going over my old work in java, looking all over the internet for answers and I cannot find what I need. I have an ordered array that input values into a method countOccurence(int [] list). I understand how the array works but my questions is;
how is the array able to move on the next number in count without creating duplicates of duplicates.

How is the array able to skip the duplicates and move all the way to the end without going over all the duplicates individually.

Here is the code.

```
public static void Calculations(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] values = {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3};

    countOccurence(values);
}

public static void countOccurence(int[] list) {
    //12 23 45 56 56 0
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length ; j++) {
            if (list[j] == i)
                count += 1
        }
        if (count != 0)
            System.out.printf("%d happens %d %s%n",
                    i, count, count > 1 ? "times" : "time");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is this program really giving you the number of occurrences? Shouldn't it be `if (list[j] == list[i])`?

Comment: That would not be the best way to execute the problem becuase the results would be like this. 0 occurs 1 time

1 occurs 4 times

2 occurs 4 times

3 occurs 4 times

4 occurs 4 times

5 occurs 1 time

Comment: This is the results that is typically needed 1 occurs 1 time

2 occurs 4 times

3 occurs 1 time

Comment: What I really need to know is how is the array intelligent enough to not count the other 2's and just jump straight to i=3. It went over the 2's in one iteration with -j- then it jump to -i- (5)

Comment: And based on your explanation about using `list[j]==i` and not `list[j]==list[i]`, why are you using the outer loop at all then? If your idea is to check for all the numbers, isn't the outer loop exit condition `i<list.length` incorrect? Shouldn't it be something like `i<maxValueInArray`?

Comment: I need the outer loop to iterate through the inner loop, comparing all index of the inner loop to a single outer loop index. I don't understand why aren't there multiple loops per inner loop only for index 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: I don't understand why after _list[j]==i_ that it does not print _list[j]==i 1_ and _list[j]==i_ 2xs and _list[j]==i_ 3xs and _list[j]==i_ 4xs

Comment: What I want to understand is why when the array meets a duplicate it does not go over a full interation. It just jumps to the next index after it counts duplicates. Is that a behavior inherent to arrays.

Comment: Array does not have any such functionality. It cannot remove or detect duplicate elements. That's not how it's designed. It's all about how you play with the loops.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's see what's happening here and I do believe there's a logical
>   flaw in this which we will discuss towards the end of this answer. :)

```
public static void Calculations(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] values = {1, 2, 2, 3}; 
    //reducing few 2s to make the explanation shorter
    countOccurence(values);
}

    public static void countOccurence(int[] list) {
        //12 23 45 56 56 0
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length ; j++) {
                if (list[j] == i)
                    count += 1
            }
            if (count != 0)
                System.out.printf("%d happens %d %s%n",
                        i, count, count > 1 ? "times" : "time");
        }
    }
    }
```

---

> Here's how it goes about: Note, I have considered this array to keep
>   it short: `int[] values = {1, 2, 2, 3};`

```
Outer-loop iteration 1: i=0
     Inner-loop iteration 1: j=0, list[j]=list[0]=1!=(i=0), count=0
     Inner-loop iteration 2: j=1, list[j]=list[0]=2!=(i=0), count=0
     Inner-loop iteration 3: j=2, list[j]=list[0]=2!=(i=0), count=0
     Inner-loop iteration 4: j=3, list[j]=list[0]=3!=(i=0), count=0
     Print count 0

count=0 again
Outer-loop iteration 2: i=1
     Inner-loop iteration 1: j=0, list[j]=list[0]=1=(i=1), count=1
     Inner-loop iteration 2: j=1, list[j]=list[0]=2!=(i=1), count=1
     Inner-loop iteration 3: j=2, list[j]=list[0]=2!=(i=1), count=1
     Inner-loop iteration 4: j=3, list[j]=list[0]=3!=(i=1), count=1
     Print count 1

count=0 again
Outer-loop iteration 3: i=2
     Inner-loop iteration 1: j=0, list[j]=list[0]=1!=(i=2), count=0
     Inner-loop iteration 2: j=1, list[j]=list[0]=2=(i=2), count=1
     Inner-loop iteration 3: j=2, list[j]=list[0]=2=(i=2), count=2
     Inner-loop iteration 4: j=3, list[j]=list[0]=3!=(i=2), count=2
     Print count 2

count=0 again
Outer-loop iteration 4: i=3
     Inner-loop iteration 1: j=0, list[j]=list[0]=1!=(i=3), count=0
     Inner-loop iteration 2: j=1, list[j]=list[0]=2!=(i=3), count=0
     Inner-loop iteration 3: j=2, list[j]=list[0]=2!=(i=3), count=0
     Inner-loop iteration 4: j=3, list[j]=list[0]=3=(i=3, count=1
     Print count 1
```

`i=4` now so `i<list.length` i.e `4<4` is not true and so it exits the outer-loop and we are done. So, this is how it works. There is no skipping over elements here. You keep incrementing the value of `i` so `i` never gets repeated. So it never prints count for duplicate elements. It is still iterating over the array like it should (in the inner-loop). It's just `i=2` will never be true again or will never happen again when `i has incremented to 3` and so `list[j]==i for i=2` will not happen more than once.

> Now, where's the issue or the flaw in this implementation?
>     This implementation will work as long as the elements or the numbers in your array are smaller than the length of the array itself.

If the original array was something like `{1,2,2,4}`, to check for the occurrences of `4`,
`i` would have to increment to `4` but the array length is also `4` and so `i<list.length` i.e `4<4` would never be true and so the number of occurrences of `4` or `any number greater than 4` won't be checked. So this implementation works perfectly as long as the elements in the array are smaller than the length of the array itself.

To correct your implementation, you may have to run a separate loop initially to get the largest number in array and then change the condition to `i<=largestNumber`.

Comment: I understood the size and limitation of the array what was my concern is here:'Outer-loop iteration 2: i=1' and here 'Outer-loop iteration 3: i=2'

Comment: Do you still have the doubt?

Comment: I get the answer so far, my doubt why doesnt the result look this way                                i=1 is equal j=0
and i =2 is equal to j = 1, j= 2  count = 2
and i = 3 is equal to j= 1, j =2  count = 2
and i = 4 is equal to j = 3

Comment: Why does it add the iteration for iteration i2 and i3 in the outer loop? That's where Im lost

Comment: For each iteration of your outer-loop, `j` will complete 4 iterations. It is because `j` is reset to `0` every time. So it will start running from `j=0` for every iteration of the outer-loop and go up to `j=3`.